# Symfony 1.4 and Webservice

Tags: web-services, symfony-1.4

I am having a IPAD Native application and a symfony 1.4 application. I am having a local sql-lite DB with the same schema as that of symfony app. Now when I click on sync in the Ipad the data has to be stored in the mysql db of the web server. Similarly if there is new data in the webserver that has to be again added in the local sql Lite. The data transfer has been done by PLIST files. I am now using a normal PLIST parser for parsing the plist and storing it in DB. Also I am using Content-Disposition mechanism for sending data.

Note: There are data from both the sides since both device and web server can add data.

Can any one help me out with this since, if we are adding data in both the sides, we may get same id(primary key). How to solve this issue. Is there any plugin to do this in symfony?.

Thanks in Advance.